# Transparent View?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I do transparent view. Can anybody help me?

I want to do just like this:

[image]

Comment: so what is prob use popupwindow with rounded corner layout and align center...

Comment: But it is transparent you know.How can i do that?

Comment: What is the problem why somebody down vote?

Answer (score 3):

create one layout and make theme as dialog in your manifest

and in your layout set background as `android:background="#885A2720"`

**EDIT:**
check this layout in your view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="380dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#885A2720" style="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not related background color etc.I want to TRANSPARENT view

Comment: without any try don't say anything. "#88   5A2720" this actually alpha color you can change the value 88 to your wish range from 00 to FF.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change the opacity/alpha of the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use relativeLayout then use imageView with height and width match_parent.
And set **alpha** of an image to 150dp.

Answer (score 0):

Use drawables to draw the rectangles

For complete transparency, use the following drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#00000000" />
   <stroke android:width="0.3dip" android:color="#2f4f4f"
       android:dashWidth="7dip"
       android:dashGap="7dip"/>
</shape>
```

If you want to set % transparency, u can set the "Alpha"property of the widget used. Note that a text box with nothing in it can help you achieve that.